# LINQ returning duplicate rows while SQL isn't

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join

I am working on a C# LINQ code using which I am trying to join two tables by grouping by a column in Table1

Below is the SQL query which returns correct results

```
SELECT
    SUM(scr.Count),spl.Name
FROM    Table1 scr
        ,Table2 spl
WHERE scr.StatusId = spl.StatusId
 GROUP by spl.Name
```

Equivalent LINQ which returns incorrect result

```
(from l in _dataContext.Table1
                     join r in
                     _dataContext.Table2 on
                     new {  l.StatusId } equals new { r.StatusId }
                     into gj
                     from r in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()                   
                     select new
                     {
                         l.Name,
                         Count = gj.Sum(j => j.Count)
                     }).GroupBy(l => l.Name).Select(x => new DataPoint
                     {
                         Name = x.Key,
                         Y = x.Sum(y => y.Count)
                     }).ToList();
```

**Wasn't able to figure the error, Is there a better way to get the results equivalent to SQL query above?**

Comment: Yes, you need to learn LINQ. It is not like SQL.

Comment: Your Linq code is doing a left join, that's what `DefaultIfEmpty` does.

Comment: Should use explicit `JOIN` in your SQL code as well.

Comment: See msdn for Left Outer  Join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verbatim equivalent would be

```
var results = (from l in db.Table1
               from r in db.Table2
               where l.StatusId == r.StatusId
               group j.Count by l.Name into g
               select new {
                   Name = g.Key,
                   Count = g.Sum()
               }).ToList();
```

The more correct join version would not use `into` with the `join` (also know as a group join) or `DefaultIfEmpty` as that results in a left join.  Instead you just use a regular group by as part of your query syntax instead of needlessly tacking it on with Method syntax.

```
var results = (from l in db.Table1
               join j in db.Table2 on l.StatusId equals r.StatusId
               group j.Count by l.Name into g
               select new {
                   Name = g.Key,
                   Count = g.Sum()
               }).ToList();
```

And if you actually want all the names then this is how you'd do a left join.

```
var results = (from l in db.Table1
               join j in db.Table2 on l.StatusId equals r.StatusId into lrs
               from lr in lrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
               group lr.Count by l.Name into g
               select new {
                   Name = g.Key,
                   Count = g.Sum()
               }).ToList();
```

Or if the `Count` column is not nullable you might have to cast it to make it work

```
group (int?)lr.Count by l.Name into g
```

Comment: Your more correct join version still uses `into` :)

Comment: @NetMage Yes, as part of the group by, not as part of the join, but I'll clarify that in the answer.

Comment: @juharr I would like to include all the names in table1 even if there is no match in table2

Comment: @DoIt That's not what your SQL is doing.

Comment: @juharr I thought so but now I would like to include them and if I use defaultifEmpty it causes redundancy again

Comment: @DoIt I've updated to add what should do the left join and give you Names without rows.  You might have to fiddle with it depending on whether `Count` is nullable or not.